# How can I display assets as a tab page?

Tags: visualforce, customsetting, configuration

I want to be able to add Assets as a tab view however it is not available for this. I have that a third party app for activities can display an Activities tab. I would like to know how to do this for Assets.
 Sample screenshot of Activities tab
[image]

[image]

illustration of activities tab
illustration of page-in-a-page (not the url

Comment: can you please share some image for the current view for Activities?

Comment: @ChetanGupta Done.

Comment: try the simple web tab to check if this meets your requirement. I am sure it will.

Comment: Tried that and I end up with assets tab page within a page (url displayed in browser is https://eu3.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.Integration?lid=01rw0000000MTvU&ic=1)

Comment: pls try this URL - "/02i?isdtp=mn".

Comment: no success with that either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't necessary anymore - as of Spring 15 there is a proper tab available.  For existing orgs you may need to make the tab visible through each profile.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend a simple Visualforce page and tab with an action that handles the redirect:

```
<apex:page tabStyle="Asset" action="/02i">
</apex:page>
```

This has the advantage of no iframe and dynamic page height, which I think outweighs the disadvantage that the tab isn't highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it worked.

Assets has a key prefix as '02i'. So if you point your URL at '/02i' it will open up the Assets tab view.

You can create a Web Tab and have the URL as '/02i?isdtp=mn' or create a VF tab and have the VF tab point to '/02i' in an iframe. Something like this..

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" tabStyle="Asset">

    <iframe src="/02i" width="100%" height="500px"/>

</apex:page>
```

[image]